# Convert pdf into word doc file

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, jasper-reports

How to convert the pdf into the word doc file?

The pdf file was generated by `JasperReports` and which has one table in which one column contains text with html body part like `<p><b>test</b></p>`

So I just want to convert this pdf file in doc with proper formating like text display in bold format.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this programmatically ? If not, then why have you included the java tag in this question ? Also, in that case this question is a better fit to http://superuser.com/ .

Comment: If you are generate the report with jasper ... can't you configure jasper to create an html or rtf file? http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/xlsformula/index.html#xlsformula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the format information is removed in converting a file into a PDF so you can not just convert it back unless the PDF was created as Marked content with additional meta tags in it.

I wrote a blog article explaining about PDF text at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2009/04/pdf-text/

Answer (score 1):

Pro grammatically you can do it with Apachi POI.  You can first read the PDF and then write it to a Word Doc using the API.